# Random Forest Classifier on a small set of labelled data

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I have around 50 rows of data which has labels. There is also a truth source in the data. The truth source describes about the end user experience.

I also have 50,000 rows of  data, but  it does not have truth source in the data.

I am planning to do the following :-
Use the 50 rows of data to construct the Random Forest Classifier.

Not sure whether the data set is very small to begin with.

I have read about Semi-Supervised Learning and here is what I understood and am going to apply it to my situation.

Using the Classifier which I get from those 50 rows apply it on the 50,000 rows of data.
Then select the topmost k rows from unlabelled data which has the least error rate or most accurate.

Add this K rows to the labelled data and then run the classifier again on this set of data and repeat the above process.

Has anyone tried this technique ?

Basically I am trying to solve the problem of classification working with a small data set and then applying to a larger data set.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to impute the missing "truth source" values for the 50,000 unlabelled observations, I do not think you gain anything by the incremental training procedure you describe. I think the best option is to just train one random forest using the 50 labelled observations and use it to impute the truth source of all the unlabelled data. To get an estimate of its performance I suggest you do repeated cross-validation.

The reason I do not think the incremental procedure adds any value is that you have no way of telling which of the unlabelled observations have the lowest prediction error. If you use some form of leaf node purity to determine how good each prediction is you just risk to retrain your classifier on overfitted results, making it worse and worse.